# Compare values from one table with the results from a query?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

First, I will explain the what is being captured. User's have a member level associated with their accounts (Bronze, Gold, Diamond, etc). A nightly job needs to run to calculate the orders from today a year back. If the order total for a given user goes over or under a certain amount their level is upgraded or downgraded. The table where the level information is stored will not change much, but the minimum and maximum amount thresholds may over time. This is what the table looks like:

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MemberAdvantageLevels] (
[Id] int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) ,
[Name] varchar(255) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL ,
[MinAmount] int NOT NULL ,
[MaxAmount] int NOT NULL ,
CONSTRAINT [PK__MemberAd__3214EC070D9DF1C7] PRIMARY KEY ([Id])
)
ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

I wrote a query that will group the orders by user for the year to date. The query includes their current member level.

```sql
SELECT
Sum(dbo.tbh_Orders.SubTotal) AS OrderTotals,
Count(dbo.UserProfile.UserId) AS UserOrders,
dbo.UserProfile.UserId,
dbo.UserProfile.UserName,
dbo.UserProfile.Email,
dbo.MemberAdvantageLevels.Name,
dbo.MemberAdvantageLevels.MinAmount,
dbo.MemberAdvantageLevels.MaxAmount,
dbo.UserMemberAdvantageLevels.LevelAchievmentDate,
dbo.UserMemberAdvantageLevels.LevelAchiementAmount,
dbo.UserMemberAdvantageLevels.IsCurrent as IsCurrentLevel,
dbo.MemberAdvantageLevels.Id as MemberLevelId,


FROM
dbo.tbh_Orders
INNER JOIN dbo.tbh_OrderStatuses ON dbo.tbh_Orders.StatusID = dbo.tbh_OrderStatuses.OrderStatusID
INNER JOIN dbo.UserProfile ON dbo.tbh_Orders.CustomerID = dbo.UserProfile.UserId
INNER JOIN dbo.UserMemberAdvantageLevels ON dbo.UserProfile.UserId = dbo.UserMemberAdvantageLevels.UserId
INNER JOIN dbo.MemberAdvantageLevels ON dbo.UserMemberAdvantageLevels.MemberAdvantageLevelId = dbo.MemberAdvantageLevels.Id
WHERE
dbo.tbh_OrderStatuses.OrderStatusID = 4 AND
(dbo.tbh_Orders.AddedDate BETWEEN dateadd(year,-1,getdate()) AND GETDATE()) and IsCurrent = 1
GROUP BY
dbo.UserProfile.UserId,
dbo.UserProfile.UserName,
dbo.UserProfile.Email,
dbo.MemberAdvantageLevels.Name,
dbo.MemberAdvantageLevels.MinAmount,
dbo.MemberAdvantageLevels.MaxAmount,
dbo.UserMemberAdvantageLevels.LevelAchievmentDate,
dbo.UserMemberAdvantageLevels.LevelAchiementAmount,
dbo.UserMemberAdvantageLevels.IsCurrent,
dbo.MemberAdvantageLevels.Id
```

So, I need to check the OrdersTotal and if it exceeds the current level threshold, I then need to find the Level that fits their current order total and create a new record with their new level.

So for example, lets say jon@doe.com currently is at bronze. The MinAmount for bronze is 0 and the MaxAmount is 999. Currently his Orders for the year are at $2500. I need to find the level that $2500 fits within and upgrade his account. I also need to check their `LevelAchievmentDate` and if it is outside of the current year we may need to demote the user if there has been no activity.

I was thinking I could create a temp table that holds the results of all levels and then somehow create a CASE statement in the query above to determine the new level. I don't know if that is possible. Or, is it better to iterate over my order results and perform additional queries? If I use the iteration pattern I know i can use the `When` statement to iterate over the rows.

**Update**

I updated my Query A bit and so far came up with this, but I may need more information than just the ID from the SubQuery

```sql
Select * into #memLevels from MemberAdvantageLevels


SELECT
Sum(dbo.tbh_Orders.SubTotal) AS OrderTotals,
Count(dbo.AZProfile.UserId) AS UserOrders,
dbo.AZProfile.UserId,
dbo.AZProfile.UserName,
dbo.AZProfile.Email,
dbo.MemberAdvantageLevels.Name,
dbo.MemberAdvantageLevels.MinAmount,
dbo.MemberAdvantageLevels.MaxAmount,
dbo.UserMemberAdvantageLevels.LevelAchievmentDate,
dbo.UserMemberAdvantageLevels.LevelAchiementAmount,
dbo.UserMemberAdvantageLevels.IsCurrent as IsCurrentLevel,
dbo.MemberAdvantageLevels.Id as MemberLevelId,

(Select Id from #memLevels where Sum(dbo.tbh_Orders.SubTotal) >= #memLevels.MinAmount and Sum(dbo.tbh_Orders.SubTotal) <= #memLevels.MaxAmount) as NewLevelId


FROM
dbo.tbh_Orders
INNER JOIN dbo.tbh_OrderStatuses ON dbo.tbh_Orders.StatusID = dbo.tbh_OrderStatuses.OrderStatusID
INNER JOIN dbo.AZProfile ON dbo.tbh_Orders.CustomerID = dbo.AZProfile.UserId
INNER JOIN dbo.UserMemberAdvantageLevels ON dbo.AZProfile.UserId = dbo.UserMemberAdvantageLevels.UserId
INNER JOIN dbo.MemberAdvantageLevels ON dbo.UserMemberAdvantageLevels.MemberAdvantageLevelId = dbo.MemberAdvantageLevels.Id
WHERE
dbo.tbh_OrderStatuses.OrderStatusID = 4 AND
(dbo.tbh_Orders.AddedDate BETWEEN dateadd(year,-1,getdate()) AND GETDATE()) and IsCurrent = 1
GROUP BY
dbo.AZProfile.UserId,
dbo.AZProfile.UserName,
dbo.AzProfile.Email,
dbo.MemberAdvantageLevels.Name,
dbo.MemberAdvantageLevels.MinAmount,
dbo.MemberAdvantageLevels.MaxAmount,
dbo.UserMemberAdvantageLevels.LevelAchievmentDate,
dbo.UserMemberAdvantageLevels.LevelAchiementAmount,
dbo.UserMemberAdvantageLevels.IsCurrent,
dbo.MemberAdvantageLevels.Id
```

Comment: The elision of irrelevant fields would make your SQL, and question, much easier to understand; and thus attract more potential answerers.

Comment: I am trying to provide context and it is not a overly complicated query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This **hasn't been syntax checked or tested** but should handle the inserts and updates you describe. The insert can be done as single statement using a derived/virtual table which contains the orders group by caluclation. Note that both the insert and update  statement be done within the same transaction to ensure no two records for the same user can end up with IsCurrent = 1

```
INSERT UserMemberAdvantageLevels (UserId, MemberAdvantageLevelId, IsCurrent,
       LevelAchiementAmount, LevelAchievmentDate)
SELECT t.UserId, mal.Id, 1, t.OrderTotals, GETDATE()
FROM
    (SELECT ulp.UserId, SUM(ord.SubTotal) OrderTotals, COUNT(ulp.UserId) UserOrders
     FROM UserLevelProfile ulp
     INNER JOIN tbh_Orders ord ON (ord.CustomerId = ulp.UserId)
     WHERE ord.StatusID = 4
           AND ord.AddedDate BETWEEN DATEADD(year,-1,GETDATE()) AND GETDATE()
     GROUP BY ulp.UserId) AS t
INNER JOIN MemberAdvantageLevels mal
ON (t.OrderTotals BETWEEN mal.MinAmount AND mal.MaxAmount)
  -- Left join needed on next line in case user doesn't currently have a level
LEFT JOIN UserMemberAdvantageLevels umal ON (umal.UserId = t.UserId)
WHERE umal.MemberAdvantageLevelId IS NULL  -- First time user has been awarded a level
      OR (mal.Id <> umal.MemberAdvantageLevelId -- Level has changed 
           AND (t.OrderTotals > umal.LevelAchiementAmount -- Acheivement has increased (promotion)
                OR t.UserOrders = 0))                -- No. of orders placed is zero (de-motion)

/* Reset IsCurrent flag where new record has been added */
UPDATE UserMemberAdvantageLevels
SET umal1.IsCurrent=0
FROM UserMemberAdvantageLevels umal1
INNER JOIN UserMemberAdvantageLevels umal2 On (umal2.UserId = umal1.UserId)
WHERE umal1.IsCurrent = 1
AND umal2.IsCurrent = 2
AND umal1.LevelAchievmentDate < umal2.LevelAchievmentDate)
```

Comment: This is pretty much what I was looking for, however, I used Mark's cte piece

Answer (score 1):

One approach:

```
with cte as
(SELECT Sum(o.SubTotal) AS OrderTotals,
        Count(p.UserId) AS UserOrders,
        p.UserId,
        p.UserName,
        p.Email,
        l.Name,
        l.MinAmount,
        l.MaxAmount,
        ul.LevelAchievmentDate,
        ul.LevelAchiementAmount,
        ul.IsCurrent as IsCurrentLevel,
        l.Id as MemberLevelId
 FROM dbo.tbh_Orders o
 INNER JOIN dbo.UserProfile p ON o.CustomerID = p.UserId
 INNER JOIN dbo.UserMemberAdvantageLevels ul ON p.UserId = ul.UserId
 INNER JOIN dbo.MemberAdvantageLevels l ON ul.MemberAdvantageLevelId = l.Id
 WHERE o.StatusID = 4 AND
       o.AddedDate BETWEEN dateadd(year,-1,getdate()) AND GETDATE() and
       IsCurrent = 1
 GROUP BY
       p.UserId, p.UserName, p.Email, l.Name, l.MinAmount, l.MaxAmount,
       ul.LevelAchievmentDate, ul.LevelAchiementAmount, ul.IsCurrent, l.Id)
select cte.*, ml.*
from cte
join #memLevels ml 
  on cte.OrderTotals >= ml.MinAmount and cte.OrderTotals <= ml.MaxAmount
```

Comment: The join on tbh_OrderStatuses isn't needed - "s.OrderStatudID = 4" can be replaced by "o.StatusID = 4". Also missing alias "l" on MemberAdvantageLevels. Basically this is the same as my answer but mine also handles inserting/updating. Yours is nicely formatted though..perhaps I'll try to improve mine.